# How to get ip address of forwarded domain using java

Tags: java

Here i have problem in getting ip address of sub-domain so can any one help me to find ip. here is my code

```
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class NewTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String address = null;
    try {
            InetAddress giriAddress = java.net.InetAddress.getByName("x.x.x");//ex :: mail.vinoth.com
            address = giriAddress.getHostAddress();
        } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
 System.out.println("Ip Address :: "+address);
  }

}
```

Comment: You want to have the "real" IP for mail.google.com or how should I understand your post?

Comment: i posted the example as mail.google.com really i dont need subdomain ip only i need for forwarded sub domain ip address

Comment: actually i need to know ip address of forwarded domain address.

Comment: I got correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this i think it will work for you.

```
                  public class AnsTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

try {

 String url = "http://mail.google.com";

   URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
     conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
    conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
     conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");

      System.out.println("Request URL ... " + url);

      boolean redirect = false;

       // normally, 3xx is redirect
            int status = conn.getResponseCode();
       if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
     if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
     || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
      || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)
     redirect = true;
 }

      System.out.println("Response Code ... " + status);

      if (redirect) {

       // get redirect url from "location" header field
         String newUrl = conn.getHeaderField("Location");

      // get the cookie if need, for login
      String cookies = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");

     // open the new connnection again
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(newUrl).openConnection();
     conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
      conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
     conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
     conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");

    System.out.println("Redirect to URL : " + newUrl);

      }
System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
      }

       }

    }
```